# Call ajax when value is inserted on database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using this method to refresh content of users uploads but i've seen twitter facebook does not actually follow this type of process..they auto refresh the content or auto update the only content as soon as data is inserted to their database.

How its possible because I've seen in twitter's process by inspect element there are no background script running or any ajax pending request !!

what is this type of scripting known as ??

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    display();
  }
                   );
  function display(){
    $.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url:"display.php",
      async:true,
      cache:true,
      timeout:1000,
      success:
      function(data){
        $('#display_content').html(data);
        setTimeout(display,100000);
      }
    }
          );
  }
  ;
```

Comment: Take a look at Web Sockets: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets

Comment: [Push technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology)

Comment: I saw all this...seems that comet needs some extra software and we have to buy those services (Correct me if i'm wrong)... I'm using Apache shared hosting So, is there any easy free way to do this ?